# Calling values from Solidity contract

Tags: solidity, testnets, truffle

I'm trying to create a contract where I can save and then call a person's 'first name', 'last name' and 'age' within the truffle console.  I'm able to *save* using the `addPerson` method, but every time I *call* method `getPeople` I receive an empty array. Here is the contact.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

  contract People {

    Person[] public people;

    struct Person {
      bytes32 firstName;
      bytes32 lastName;
      uint age;

    }
    function addPerson(bytes32 _firstName, bytes32 _lastName, uint _age) returns (bool success) {

      Person memory newPerson;
      newPerson.firstName = _firstName;
      newPerson.lastName = _lastName;
      newPerson.age = _age;

      people.push(newPerson);
      return true;
    }
    function getPeople() constant returns (bytes32[], bytes32[],uint[]) {

      uint length = people.length;

      bytes32[] memory firstNames = new bytes32[](length);
      bytes32[] memory lastNames = new bytes32[](length);
      uint[] memory ages = new uint[](length);

      for(uint i=0; i < people.length; i++) {
        Person memory currentPerson;
        currentPerson = people[i];

        firstNames[i] = currentPerson.firstName;
        lastNames[i] = currentPerson.lastName;
        ages[i] = currentPerson.age;
      }
      return (firstNames, lastNames, ages);

    }

  }
```

It seems to be working. I was able to compile and migrate it using `truffle compile` and `truffle migrate`.

I'm running `testrpc` in the terminal. And it seems like my transactions are accurately being recorded.

[image]

I'm interacting with the contract via `truffle console`. When I enter in the command `People.deployed().abi` and `People.deployed().address()` I get a value.

[image]

I can enter info using the `addPerson` method:

`People.deployed.addPerson('Darlene', 'Brown', 25)`

I don't know why when I call `getPeople` I get back an empty array

`truffle(default)> People.deployed().getPeople().then(console.log)
[ [], [], [] ]
undefined`

Comment: Have you tried accessing a specific person manually? I'm not familiar with Truffle, but `People.deployed().people(0)` should return the first Person as an array.

Comment: It seems to be working when I tried the code in [browser-solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.8+commit.60cc1668.js). It's possible it's a truffle-specific issue, or has to do with compiler versions.

Comment: When I tried accessing the first value value 

`People.deployed().people(0).then(console.log)`

I get this as a result:

`[ '0x', '0x', { [String: '0'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] } ]`

Next, I will try the code in browser-solidity.

Comment: That would indicate people aren't being added. All of those values are basically 0. But looks like your question's already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable length values such as dynamic arrays and strings can be returned from functions in the same contract, but they can't be successfully used for communication between contracts or the outside world because the *ABI requires strictly fixed-length* arguments.

The idea of returning the whole list is an anti-pattern, in my opinion. I agree with Mathew that the public people getter should work as expected, or you can add an explicit function. Avoid looping where possible (nearly always where data storage is concerned) because of gas cost and other factors.

Below I added a function to also return the array length for people so an external client can know how many rows exist. The client can do the looping operation, if needed, such as getting the whole list.

This "add only" interable storage pattern can be extended to support "delete" with a few more lines if you need that as well.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract People {

    Person[] public people;

    struct Person {
      bytes32 firstName;
      bytes32 lastName;
      uint age;
    }

    function addPerson(bytes32 firstName, bytes32 lastName, uint age) returns (bool success) {

      Person memory newPerson;
      newPerson.firstName = firstName;
      newPerson.lastName = lastName;
      newPerson.age = age;

      people.push(newPerson);
      return true;
    }

    function getPerson(uint index) constant returns(bytes32 firstName, bytes32 lastName, uint age) {
        // return value should be an array with three elements
        return (people[index].firstName, people[index].lastName, people[index].age);
    }

    function getPersonCount() constant returns(uint count) {
        return people.length;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this code correctly on Truffle v.3.x where the `People.deployed()` object returns a promise. Not sure if this applies to your version of Truffle (looks like v.2.x) but you're missing the double parentheses on your `deployed` function call here: `People.deployed.addPerson('Darlene', 'Brown', 25)` which may be the reason you are not able to add values to `people`.